# Not sure which join to use

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I have data like below in 2 tables,

| RollNum | lang_opted |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 5 |
| 3 | 4 |

**Lang_table**

| lang_id | lang |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | lang1 |
| 2 | lang2 |
| 3 | lang3 |
| 4 | lang4 |
| 5 | lang5 |

I need to join the above two tables and get data like below,

We have this data in Oracle. Pls suggest suggest a query to get this result.

| RollNum | lang1 | lang2 | lang3 | lang4 | lang5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Y | Y | N | N | N |
| 2 | N | N | N | N | Y |
| 3 | N | N | N | Y | N |

Tried left join, cross join, pivot, not exists but still couldn't get the expected result.

Comment: Try searching for the term "pivot"

Comment: You are probably looking for dynamic SQL. That means you need two queries: A first one to get all langs from the lang table. With this data you build the final query. In order to do that you need a programming language. Either use Oracle's built-in PL/SQL or use any other language like C#, Java, whatever. Or just select the data from the two tables and then loop through the results and build the desired grid you want to show in your app yourself.

Comment: A remark on why this is so complicated: A query result is a table (albeit one that isn't stored in the database). It consists of defined columns and a variable number of rows. But the result columns you are showing are probably not fixed, but variable themselves, as they seem to be a result from querying the lang table. So you want data (values in your lang table) become structure (columns in your query result). This cannot be done with a single SQL query.

Comment: How many languages do you have? Can this be treated as a fixed number? The answer is **WAY simpler** if you can "hard code" those column headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unlikely that you have so many languages that you really need "dynamic SQL" So, if you can accept hard-coding the languages as column headings then you can use simple "conditional aggregates"

```
Select
    t.rollnum
  , max(case when l.lang = 'lang1' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as 'lang1'
  , max(case when l.lang = 'lang2' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as 'lang2'
  , max(case when l.lang = 'lang3' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as 'lang3'
  , max(case when l.lang = 'lang4' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as 'lang4'
  , max(case when l.lang = 'lang5' then 'Y' else 'N' end) as 'lang5'
from your_table t
inner join lang_table l on t.lang_opted = l.lang_id
group by
    t.rollnum
```

You could use "pivot" but frankly I believe the above is simpler.and you can arrange the columns in any order you want. If you add a new language at any time just add another conditional aggregate with heading to suit.

Comment: That worked thanks @paul. Earlier I tried inner join but without max( case...) so I didn't get the expected result.